# Login issue: Can't type anything! (SSH connect to host -> Connection timed out): Lost connection

Tags: pi-3, ssh

I hope someone can help me out. I couldn't find anything about this on different forums. I am having issues while starting up the Pi. It keeps giving me message that the permission is denied and that the connection is lost.
That goes on and on. I can't typ anything because the text is coming back over and over again.
I tried to change the cdmline text file with the additional text:
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait init=/bin/sh

I hope someone can help.
Much appreciated!!

Kind regards,
Noud

P.S. I am using a Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: You don't need to use ssh if you are using the console login via the serial link.  You need to explain precisely what you are doing.

Comment: The point to the duplicate is that "connection timed out" means something specific -- and it is *not* a message from the Pi.   If this is not what you meant (the question is **very unclear**), you need to ask about the problem in a more coherent way.